# MySQL: How to optimize when there's only one client ever?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

MySQL naturally has many features to allow possibly concurrent access by multiple clients, like locking, etc. These cause an overhead which can be taxing for very large tables (right?).

What if I do not need to serve to multiple clients? I have a very large table (~150 million rows) on my machine, and I'm the only one accessing the data for a scientific project. So there is only one active client at a time, and virtually no chance of corruption.

How can I avoid some of the overhead caused by MySQL's protective measures and speed up my queries?

In this particular case, is there an advantage to either of the MyISAM of InnoDb engines?

Comment: take a look at `ISOLATION LEVELS`  http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3393161/MySQL-Transactions-Part-II---Transaction-Isolation-Levels.htm

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is make sure you're database and data-access code is implemented efficiently. There isn't much performance to be gained by stripping away concurrency safeguards but there may be places you are doing something very inefficiently. Have a look at the performance schema to get more insight into this if you are experiencing any performance issues then tune the database the same way you would if there were multiple clients.